# A unitary matrix of functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, matrix-analysis

If $A(z)=[A_{ij} (z)] $ is an $n\times n$  unitary matrix valued functions. Is there a characterization of such matrix if:

(1)  the entries are analytic functions on a set $D$.

and

(2)  if the entries are entire functions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The entries are bounded (by $1$), hence if they are entire functions, they are constant.

Comment: I think that question (1) was reasonable, since it is not necessarily the case that researchers in one area of maths would know the tools used in Alexandre Eremenko's elegant answer

Comment: @abx. Thank you, that make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Such matrices can exist only if their entries are constant. For entire functions
this is proved in he remark of @abx. For analytic functions in any other region this can be proved as follows: the entiries of the $j$-th column of
your matrix must satisfy
$$|a_{1,j}|^2+\ldots+|a_{m,j}|^2=1.$$
Notice that $|a_{ij}|^2$ are subharmonic, and their sum is harmonic. Therefore they
must be all harmonic, but it is easy to see (for example, by using Cauchy-Riemann equations) that for an analytic function $|f|^2$
can be harmonic only if $f$ is constant.